# send data from php to javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a vertical timeline, but I don't know how to get the data in the correct form from the db using php.

the code to add the events is the following:

```
$(function() {
  $("#element").timeline({
    data: [
      {time: new Date(),
        color: '#555',
        css: 'success',
        content: 'jquery.timeline Demo Event 1'},
      {time: new Date(),
        color: '#00ff00',
        css: 'success',
        content: 'jquery.timeline Demo Event 2'},
      {time: new Date(),
        color: '#000',
        css: 'success',
        content: 'jquery.timeline Demo Event 3'},
      {time: new Date(),
        color: '#000',
        css: 'success',
        content: 'jquery.timeline Demo Event 4'}
    ]
  });
```

I set up a get.php and I can get the data from db in this way:

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "";

  // Create connection
  $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT NAME, TEXT, DATE FROM TABLE";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["NAME"]. " - Name: " . $row["TEXT"]. " " . $row["DATE"]. "<br>";

    }
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
  }
  $conn->close();
?>
```

How would I put all the retrieved contents inside the event handler?

```
$(function() {
  $("#element").timeline({
    data: [
      {time: date_event_1,
        color: color_event_1,
        css: 'success',
        content: content_event_1},
      ...
                  ...

    ]
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ideal is to request the php via ajax call, retrieve the database info,  construct an array of objects that resembles the data the jQuery Plug-in expects,  and pass it in there. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: I think the Ideal here would be to use the jQuery to make the $.post with the data to grab the info handle that in PHP as you're doing now but in the php instead of making echo "id: " ..... echo a JSON string, it's easier to be handled in again in jquery/javascript

Comment: Yes, I've done it, but now I'm facing this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in [  that seems to be related to Json, I opened another topic here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495235/jquery-error-cannot-use-in-operator-to-search-for-0-in